# for-loop + Arrow Anti Pattern VS for-loop + continue

Tags: java, design-patterns, anti-patterns

Do you think the following fragment of code (for-loop + continue)

```
for (Identity fileIdentity : fileIdentities) {
      totalFileCount++;
      if (!forceTheStatus(params, fileIdentity))
        continue;
      updatedFileCount++;
      if (!params.shouldUpdateLinkedEntity())
        continue;
      Optional<Identity> batchIdentity = getLinkedBatchIdentity(fileIdentity);
      if (!batchIdentity.isPresent())
        continue;
      totalBatchCount++;
      if (!getRemittanceProcessor().forceTheStatus(params, batchIdentity.get()))
        continue;
      updatedBatchCount++;
}
```

is better than this other (for-loop + Arrow Anti Pattern)? And why?

```
for (Identity fileIdentity : fileIdentities) {
      totalFileCount++;
      if (forceTheStatus(params, fileIdentity)) {
        updatedFileCount++;
        if (params.shouldUpdateLinkedEntity()) {
          Optional<Identity> batchIdentity = getLinkedBatchIdentity(fileIdentity);
          if (batchIdentity.isPresent()) {
            totalBatchCount++;
            if (getRemittanceProcessor().forceTheStatus(params, batchIdentity.get()))
              updatedBatchCount++;
          }
        }
      }
}
```

To me the solution with continue looks harder to understand, but on the other hand we have an anti-pattern :(

Comment: *antipattern*, IMHO, is a staff that harder to *read*, *maintain*, *support* etc. In your case, it's the 1st chunk. The number of `if`s (and their levels) means nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of both solutions is readable. Do not use continue and do not create too many nested ifs in one method.

I suggest:

1. **Split** your code into smaller pieces
2. **Document** your code
3. Try to use **meaningful names**

Of course I don't understand what your methods and variables do, but I tried to create a fictional example, of what restructured, documented code could look like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Snippet {

    /** The total number of all files, that were inspected */
    private int totalFileCount;

    /** The number of files that have been modified in any kind of way */
    private int updatedFileCount;

    /** The number of files, that were put into batch processing */
    private int totalBatchCount;

    /** The number of files, that have successfully been processed by the batch */
    private int updatedBatchCount;

    /** inspects all files, processes them, if required */
    private void processFiles(Parameters params, Iterable<Identity> fileIdentities) {
        for (Identity fileIdentity : fileIdentities)
            processFile(params, fileIdentity);
    }

    /** inspects a single file, processes it, if required */
    private void processFile(Parameters params, Identity fileIdentity) {
        totalFileCount++;
        if (forceTheStatus(params, fileIdentity))
            updateFile(params, fileIdentity);
    }

    /** updates the file, and - if necessary - updates the linked entity */
    private void updateFile(Parameters params, Identity fileIdentity) {
        updatedFileCount++;
        if (params.shouldUpdateLinkedEntity())
            updateLinkedEntity(params, fileIdentity);
    }

    /** puts the linked entity into the batch processing queue (if any exists) */
    private void updateLinkedEntity(Parameters params, Identity fileIdentity) {
        Optional<Identity> batchIdentity = getLinkedBatchIdentity(fileIdentity);
        if (batchIdentity.isPresent())
            batchUpdateLinkedEntity(params, batchIdentity);
    }

    /**
      * puts the linked entity into the batch processing queue
      * and uses the remittance processor
      */
    private void batchUpdateLinkedEntity(Parameters params, Optional<Identity> batchIdentity) {
        totalBatchCount++;
        if (getRemittanceProcessor().forceTheStatus(params, batchIdentity.get()))
            updatedBatchCount++;
    }

    // Dummy implementations to make the code compilable

    public static class Parameters {
        public boolean shouldUpdateLinkedEntity() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static class Identity {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterable<Identity> fileIdentities = Arrays.asList(new Identity());
        new Snippet().processFiles(new Parameters(), fileIdentities);
    }

    private Snippet getRemittanceProcessor() {
        return null;
    }

    private Optional<Identity> getLinkedBatchIdentity(Identity fileIdentity) {
        return null;
    }

    private boolean forceTheStatus(Object params, Identity fileIdentity) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is ok and I prefer it too, but, my colleagues say it introduces a lot of code more that leads to less readability ...

Comment: i don't understand whats bad about "continue". the only problem i see are the missing "{", "}".

Comment: i personally don't like that much depth in methods, it gets out of control.
there shouldn't be more than depth=3 of method invocations.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for continue. But probably you can map the states to an enum and then use switch/case?

Comment: In my case it is hard to map the states to an enum... I also think such a change will lead to less readability.